# SVG: How to use an unclosed path as a clip path

Tags: svg

Is it possible to clip an SVG element to an unclosed path (e.g. a straight line)?

For example:

```
<svg>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="blue" clip-path="url(#mask)"></rect>    
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="mask">
        <path stroke-width="10" stroke="white" d="M 0 0 L 100 100"></path>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use that as a clipPath but it will clip everything because [stroke doesn't count for clipPaths](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/masking.html#EstablishingANewClippingPath).

> The raw geometry of each child element exclusive of rendering properties such as ‘fill’, ‘stroke’, ‘stroke-width’ within a ‘clipPath’ conceptually defines a 1-bit mask